# Добавить массив данных в модель

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет.

Помогите найти праильное решение.
Мне на сервер приходят данные вот в таком виде. Фото ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первые два поля я добавлю в нужную мне таблицу.

Вопрос с другими полями (ingredient-id, amount). В БД есть таблица. Фото ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно для рецепта добавить все ингредиенты. На сервер пришли id ингредиентов. Нужно как-то прокрутить грамотно этот массив и сделать запрос в БД.

1. Как можно вернуть id только что добавленного рецепта, чтобы потом к нему добавлять ингредиенты?
2. Можно ли как-то собрать из пришедшего массива id-ингредиентов и количество и вставить в БД для одного рецепта, но чтобы не в цикле, а одним запросом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это классическое отношение между моделями "многие ко многим". в `Laravel` это называется [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).
Я так понимаю из скриншота у вас как раз смежная (intermediate) таблица, в которую помещаются `id` рецепта и `id` ингридиента.

Соответственно,чтобы то, что вы хотите сделать, грамотно заработало у вас должно быть 3 таблицы:
1) recipes
2) ingredients
3) ingredient_recipe

Модель Recipe:

```
class Recipe extends Model
{
   public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingredient','ingredient_recipe');
    }
}
```

Модель Ingredient:

```
class Ingredient extends Model
    {
       public function recipes()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Recipe','ingredient_recipe');
        }
    }
```

Необходимо первоначально создать какой-либо рецепт:

```
$new_recipe = Recipe::create(["name" => "my_recipe","description" => "very tasty"]);
```

Это ответ на первый вопрос, где `$new_recipe->id` будет `id` нового рецепта.
Далее надо собрать массив из `id` ингредиентов, например через метод коллекции [pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck), допустим `$arr_ingredients = [1,2,3]` и выполнить:

```
$new_recipe->ingredients()->sync($arr_ingredients);
```

Это ответ на второй вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Всё отлчно расписали :)

А вот как можно грамотно перебрать пришедший массив, чтобы выбрать только ингредиенты и их количество?  Есть идея сделать это обычным foreach и сделать ассоциативный массив с id-рецепта и его количеством

Comment: Конечно изначально было бы правильнее присылать на сервер корректные данные, чтобы был объект `recipe`, который имел бы массив `ingredients`. Но в этой ситуации как из вариантов это простой перебор через foreach, других вариантов с ходу предложить пока не могу

Comment: Ок, спасибо за помощь